# Warnings displayed in cells while exporting jasper report in excel format for different data types used in cross tab measure

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReport 4.5.1. Using cross-tab with measures of different data-types namely date and double data-type. Problem is while exporting report in excel, execl gives warning as number stored as text. I cannot handle this in SQL query. I have tried using property  in jasper report. But this property has no effect on excel report. I have seen other posts on stackoverflow.com, none of them matches with this requirement. 
To display date data-type i have used in measure expression as,
$V{COL1}.equals("FSI") ? new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(java.util.Date($V{COL2Measure}.toString())) : new Double(Double.parseDouble($V{COL2Measure}))

It displays date properly in execl without any warnings. But after type-casting to double still it shows warnings in excel report for numbers. Also Expression class is "java.lang.String". I cannot change it to number or double beacuse date type does not works.I changed expression class to "java.lang.Object", then it gives error in while type casting to Double that be applied to Object.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One more point, through Query all the measures are returned as character data-type. i want to handle this in ireport, because it is not possible to handle in data-base query

Comment: SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(java.util.Date($V{COL2Measure}.toString()))  is String.
new Double(Double.parseDouble($V{COL2Measure})) is Double.
Is it the same field (measure)? Question is unclear

Comment: In cross-tab measure, i have to use two different measures of data type date and double. Measure class is of String data-type. I am stuck on this. Now i am displaying as it is and i am getting warnings in excel for number data-types :(

Comment: You must make measure as Double. After that (if you make export from iReport) set Tools/Options/Export options/Excel set "Detect cell type" checked. 
"I cannot change it to number or double beacuse date type does not works". Why? Is it stacktrace error or something else?

Comment: I have checked detect cell type=true. Also if i changed measure class as "Double". It gives error cannot cast String to Double. As i have two types of data as measure namely Date and Number.